# RoutedEventArgs vs EventArgs

Tags: .net, wpf, events, routed-events

I am learning WPF / Silverlight and saw in an MS vidcast that it is now recommended to use `RoutedEventArgs` over `EventArgs`; although it didn't say exactly why.

I have a win forms app that uses interfaces for "widgets" in an attempt to not be tied to a specific display technology (in Presenters / ViewModels), so if my IButton Click event now needs to take the `RoutedEventArgs` now I guess it isn't as useful.

Can someone please explain if I should switch to `RoutedEventArgs` in all cases and why?

As an aside, does anyone else have experience / opinions about using interface widgets as I'm describing them?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, basically a `RoutedEvent` travels through the `Logical` tree, either from the source element to root element (`Bubble` event route) or, less frequently from root element to sub levels elements (`Tunnel` event route). What this means is that if you have a `Button` inside of a `StackPanel`, that itself is inside of a `Grid`; if you define a `Click` event in the controls they will all trigger it unless one of them *handles* it.

If the event route is `Bubble` (named as a regular event `Click`), it will go:

`Button -> StackPanel -> Grid`

If the event route is `Tunnel` (named `PreviewClick`), it will go the other way around:

`Grid -> StackPanel -> Button`

So now with the *handling*, it's pretty simple. If it's a `Bubble` route and the `Button` sets the `RoutedEventArgs.Handled` to true, that `StackPanel` and `Grid` will not trigger it. Same with the `RoutedEvent`, if the `Grid` handles it, the `StackPanel` and `Button` will not trigger it.

This is my understanding in a nutshell, I avoided some stuff for simplicity.

I recommend [this chapter](http://books.google.com/books?id=XWu70Oqz6RIC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=wpf+%5C%22sharing+resources+between+assemblies%22&source=bl&ots=FMQU9g3whX&sig=rhK8YR-OUddEKmSBMqZXv45gxNc&hl=en&ei=JlqpSqf5NNKBtge6jqXYBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1%23v=onepage&q=wpf%2520%2522sharing%2520resources%2520between%2520assemblies%2522&f=false) for better understanding of this WPF feature.

Comment: @CodeBlend no pain, no gain!

Comment: Simple and concise explanation. In what case would you need to use a Tunnel event? I can't think of any practical uses.

Comment: Tunneling (PreviewClick) happens before bubbling (Click). You can use / abuse this fact, as I do. When my WPF app user clicks a button to show a child window, my tunneling event closes all current child windows and then my bubbling event opens the new child window.

Answer (score 3):

RoutedEventArgs is a new type of event argument that exists to support the WPF model of eventing: Routed Events.  It's hard to explain in a short entry why exactly WPF chose this model or what the point is so I'll start by pointing you to a good article on the subject.

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(VS.85).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a Button element containing other elements, a StackPanel, itself containing a TextBox and an Image element.

The Button element should be able to handle a click event no matter if the Image that got clicked or if the TextBox was.

Hence WPF provides a way to :

- Propagate an event through element tree most of the time bubbling
  from  the source element (here say the Image), to a higher level toward root element (for instance the button here).
- Handle such a propagated event.