# Failed to assign to property when adding new ApplicationBarMenuItem icon

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, shell, application-bar

I've added a new `ApplicationBarMenu` button with icon to a page in my wp7 project. when trying to run the page i get :

> Failed to assign to property
>   'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton.Click'. [Line: 56
>   Position: 124]

Which points to the new menu item button i have added (the second one, `send_report_button` ):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="take_photo_button" IconUri="/Images/appbar.feature.camera.rest.png" Text="Take photo" Click="TakePhotoClick" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="send_report_button" IconUri="/Images/mail.sent.png" Text="Send report" Click="SendReportClick" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="logout_button" IconUri="/Images/appbar.logout.rest.png" Text="Logout"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <!--<shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuItem1" Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuItem2" Text="MenuItem 2"/>-->
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

I have checked ten times that i have a method in the `.xaml.cs` :

```
private void SendReportClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

But still, VS doesnt seem to recognize it, or something else is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in the event handler signature. You have `RoutedEventArgs` as the second parameter. It should just be `EventArgs`.

[Here is an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1428775/303696). Don't forget that the app bar is a shell object.