# what means "object sender, RoutedEventArgs e" in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

what means exactly (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) when declaring a method in c#, "sender" and "e" are parameters received by the method? what they contain?

```
private void DoWhenClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  //... code
  }
```

Comment: See this two links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303145/net-events-what-are-object-sender-eventargs-e
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428037/routedeventargs-vs-eventargs

Comment: Grab CLR Via C#, skip the first two chapters, and read.